# vb.net - How do you format currency while it is being typed in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, format, currency

The result when a number is typed.

ex:
0.01
0.11
1.11
11.11
...

How can your format this? Cents First, Then Dollars as it is being typed?

Comment: masked TextBoxes be the best option for you

Answer (score 0):

The question does not clearly state if this is `HTML` or another user interface, but I will assume `HTML`. In order to change the input direction from left-to-right into right-to-left, you can use the `CSS direction` property.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rtl {
        direction: rtl;
    }
</style>
<input type="text" id="myfield" class="rtl" />
```

The following values are available for the `CSS direction` property:

```
ltr         The writing direction is left-to-right. This is default
rtl         The writing direction is right-to-left.
initial     Sets this property to its default value.
inherit     Inherits this property from its parent element.
```